# Can you make Visual Studio 2005 provide command line arguments for your startup program?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, visual-c++-2005

For testing purposes, is there some place in the Visual Studio IDE where you can specify the command line parameters that you want sent to your startup project when it's launched from the IDE?

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes - click on Properties for your project, then Debugging, then Command Arguments.  You can type in your command line arguments there, and they will be passed to your application on startup.